# Prominent tags needing descriptions - want to get your tag editor badge?

Tags: discussion, tagging, badges

Are you a good writer? Do you have a few minutes to spare? Why not update some tags and get the tag editor badge!

Our [tags](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags) generally have some pretty good descriptions. However, we could do with a review.  Most commonly, non-pluralised tags need to be found and flagged/fixed (eg [trains](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trains) is correct, [train](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/train) is not).

See any synonyms you could suggest? Consider it.

We have a lot of tags that are quite detailed, while others, eg [cambodia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cambodia) had a one line 'it's a country in SE asia' style tag.  We could be adding in details, maps and more.

'things to do outside' for [tag:outdoor activities] is another one that could be improved.

I could edit them, and have done so for many, but if you've not gotten your badge (only <strike>90</strike> [143](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/badges/58?page=1) have!) maybe it's time to go for it, and we can all benefit as a result :)

<strike>I went through and I think the first blank tags start on [page 12](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags?page=12&tab=popular) with [night-transport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/night-transport).</strike>

Go forth!

Comment: By the way, tag wikis **must not be definitions of the tag word!** Well only if the word is rare or technical. Otherwise it should say what the tag is for. There are SE blog posts and SE meta threads on this topic. For instance I just fixed one such tag wiki for [tag:firearms].

Comment: The 'visa-rejection' tag is wrong, even though 'rejection' and 'denial' are common vernacular. There's no such thing as a 'denial outside of the US. And 'rejection' occurs because of postage, sent to the wrong place, or other mechanical errors.  Visas are 'refused'

Comment: @GayotFow worth a separate post about how we might re-tag that, people are likely to miss that in here.

Comment: @MarkMayo, you mean a question here in META about those tags?

Comment: @GayotFow yep, definitely not on the main site :)

Comment: A question outlining the fixes that should be made? I edited a wiki question earlier and apparently infringed upon a pride of authorship thing and my stuff got rolled back. How likely is that to happen again on tags and tag definitions?

Comment: @GayotFow: I don't think tag wikis even have rollback. Although officially SE says Qs and As don't have ownership, they often seem to. But that doesn't seem to happen with tags. We just keep editing them as we see problems in them. Sometimes we discuss them on meta if it's tricky or contentious.

Comment: **Relevant blog posts** on tag wikis not being word definitions: [Redesigned Tags Page](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) ... **Relevant meta topics**: [What is a tag wiki? How do I write a good one?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337) ... [Can we get a “generic definition” rejection reason for suggested tag wiki edits?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117017)

Comment: @GayotFow really? on a wiki? That's pretty unusual :(
 Usually not, tag wikis don't have ownership, but if you're new enough they'll go up in the approval queue.  And then as hippie says, if there's a question about a tag that's an issue or contentious, we raise a meta q about it.

Comment: I wrote a query that might be helpful, it shows tags with empty excerpts or bodies. Try it here: http://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/257366/find-tags-with-empty-excerpts-or-details

Comment: @SpaceDog, nice work, I'm posting it in the chat.

Comment: @pnuts Odd, maybe they changed the database or I screwed it up the first time. Here's a [better query](http://data.stackexchange.com/travel/revision/257366/704521/find-tags-with-empty-excerpts-or-details) that should be complete but is probably not the most efficient way to do it (it's been a while since I've had to write SQL)